# How to open a dialog window on press of @ key in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This the code that I've written but I am getting the full string and the function is only triggered if the first character is @. I want it to check for every instance of @ and whenever the @ key is pressed i want to open the dialog. I tried using the `onKeyDown()` but couldn't make it work.

```
override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
viewModel.onDoubtTextChanged(editable.toString())
if (editable.toString() == "@") {
openUserSuggestionDialog(doubtDescription.users as ArrayList<User>,viewModel)
}
```

`editable` contains the value which is being inputted into the TextView

Comment: So you have an EditText box where you are entering the String and upon the '@'  value being entered the dialog should pop up?

Comment: @whiterabbitj Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a on TextChange Listener to your editText

```
 editable.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //get the last String entered
                String lala = editable.getText().toString();
                String subChar = lala.substring(lala.length() - 1);
                     if(subChar.equals("@"))
                      openUserSuggestionDialog(doubtDescription.users as ArrayList<User>,viewModel)


            }
```

Comment: But I've already written this logic in `afterTextChanged` function

Comment: well thanks for updating it now. But you clearly can see what is happening, It is taking the whole String(works if you type in @ first) you need to use onTextChanged instead of afterTextChanged to get individual characters

Comment: But CharSequence s also is taking the full string.

Comment: ok updated the answer try that @MoviesFUn BTW did not know you using kotlin before started answering the question